# iOS UICollectionView - default flow, fill rows from right to left

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm using in one of my apps UICollectionView, with custom cells but with default flow.
Currently this view shows 3 cells in a row (all of them the same size). The cells fill the row from left to right, but I need it from right to left.

Is it possible? Do I need to create custom flow layout? If so, anyone can give a simple example?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you are expecting ONLY three cells, and using a header view for this collection view, you will need to perform the following steps:

override UICollectionViewFlowLayout

```
@interface GSRightToLeftCollectionViewFlowLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout
```

(GS is for Groboot SmarTech :))

the .m should look like this:

```
#import "GSRightToLeftCollectionViewFlowLayout.h"

typedef enum {
    // enum for comfortibility.
    CellXPositionLeft = 1,
    CellXpositionRight = 2,
    CellXpositionCenter = 3,
    CellXPositionNone = 4
} CellXPosition;

@interface GSRightToLeftCollectionViewFlowLayout ()

@property (nonatomic) BOOL cellFlag;
@property (nonatomic) float cellLeftX;
@property (nonatomic) float cellMiddleX;
@property (nonatomic) float cellRightX;

@end

@implementation GSRightToLeftCollectionViewFlowLayout

// when ever the bounds change, call layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:
- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSMutableArray *allItems = [[super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect] mutableCopy];

    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attribute in allItems) {

        // when we get an item, calculate it's English writing position,
        // so that we can convert it to the Hebrew - Arabic position.
        if (!self.cellFlag) {

            [self calculateLocationsForCellsWithAttribute:attribute];

            self.cellFlag = YES;
        }

        // if it's a header, do not change it's place.
        if (attribute.representedElementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {

            continue;
        }

        // check where the item should be placed.
        CellXPosition position = [self attributeForPosition:attribute];

        switch (position) {
            case CellXPositionLeft:
                attribute.frame = CGRectMake(self.cellLeftX, attribute.frame.origin.y, attribute.frame.size.width, attribute.frame.size.height);
                break;
            case CellXpositionRight:
                attribute.frame = CGRectMake(self.cellRightX, attribute.frame.origin.y, attribute.frame.size.width, attribute.frame.size.height);
                break;
            case CellXpositionCenter:
                attribute.frame = CGRectMake(self.cellMiddleX, attribute.frame.origin.y, attribute.frame.size.width, attribute.frame.size.height);
                break;
            case CellXPositionNone:
                NSLog(@"warning");
                break;
        }
    }

    return allItems;
}


- (CellXPosition)attributeForPosition:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)attribute
{
    CellXPosition cellXposition = CellXPositionNone;

    // we will return an opposite answer
    if (attribute.indexPath.row % 3 == 0) {

        // if it's in the left side, move it to the right
        cellXposition = CellXpositionRight;

    } else if (attribute.indexPath.row % 3 == 1) {

        cellXposition = CellXpositionCenter;

    } else if (attribute.indexPath.row % 3) {

        // if it's in the right side, move it to the left
        cellXposition = CellXPositionLeft;
    }

    return cellXposition;
}

- (void)calculateLocationsForCellsWithAttribute:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)attribute
{
    float cellWidth = self.itemSize.width;
    float minimumX = self.sectionInset.left;
    float maximumX = self.sectionInset.right;
    float displayWidth = self.collectionView.contentSize.width - minimumX - maximumX;
    // on iOS6, displayWidth will be 0 (don't know why), so insert an if (displayWidth == 0) and set manually the size.

    self.cellLeftX = minimumX;
    float space = (displayWidth - cellWidth * 3) / 2;
    self.cellMiddleX = self.cellRightX + cellWidth + space;
    self.cellRightX = self.cellMiddleX + cellWidth + space;
}

@end
```

In the Class which you display the CollectionView, you need to do this:

if you are using storyboards:
1. change the collectionView layout to custom (in the attribute inspector)
2. set it's class to GSRightToLeftCollectionViewFlowLayout.
3. in ViewDidLoad (or whenever you perform initialization)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    GSRightToLeftCollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[GSRightToLeftCollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(98, 138); // set the item size.
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1; // other layout properties.
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1; // other layout properties.
    layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(50, 18);
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
    // in case you use headers / footers. this is also where you would register a Cell if you don't use storyboards.
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[GSReusableView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView"];
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout;
}
```

Comment: If i have to use this code for infinite number of cells that too horizontal what changes i have to do in the code..

Comment: can you be more specific @Leena?
does the collectionView scrolls horizontally or vertically?

the **code** doesn't limit the number of cells / items, it only changes the attributes of an item. do you mean you have an infinite number of items in one row? could you upload a visual representation of the collection view you want to create?

Comment: let it be i applied alternate solution for layout thanks for the reply.

Comment: amazingly useful answer - thanks!  the only way I could solve my problem .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916006  ... was using your example code for layoutAttributesForElementsInRect and moving it down 35, for goodness sake!  :O

Comment: @Leena can you share your  alternate solution?

Answer (score 5):

i had the same issue because of an arabic translation.

Here's my solution:
Create a subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout and overwrite

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect:
```

I used NSLocales character direction as trigger for the RTL translation. If it's an LTR language, it just returns the default attributes.

Hope it's helpful.

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSArray *supersAttributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
    NSLocale *currentLocale = ((NSLocale *) [NSLocale currentLocale]);
    NSLocaleLanguageDirection direction = [NSLocale characterDirectionForLanguage:currentLocale.localeIdentifier];

    // if it's an RTL language: change the frame
    if (direction == NSLocaleLanguageDirectionRightToLeft) {
        for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes in supersAttributes) {
            CGRect frame = attributes.frame;
            frame.origin.x = rect.size.width - attributes.frame.size.width - attributes.frame.origin.x;
            attributes.frame = frame;
        }
    }
    return supersAttributes;
}
```

Comment: thank you, sir! the problem i'm currently having with this is that it no longer preserves the single row, and is instead trying to add items in a new row. if you have any pointers, they're appreciated, while i research the issue myself.:) This is useful in a situation where you may want to "push" elements onto a UICollectionview.

Comment: Minor point, but `supersAttributes` doesn't need to be mutable.

Comment: When I use this, the items just disappear. Is there anything special I need to do to make this work? Is it because my view is wide enough to scroll?

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation CollectionReversedLayout
- (void)reverseLayoutAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)attributes {
     CGPoint newCenter = attributes.center;
     newCenter.x = self.collectionViewContentSize.width - newCenter.x;
     attributes.center = newCenter;
     return attributes;
}

- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSArray *s = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes in s) {
        [self reverseLayoutAttributes:attributes];
    }
    return s;
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *s = [super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self reverseLayoutAttributes:s];
    return s;
}
```