# UICollectionView Cell Right to left display

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I need to display `UICollectionView` in the following manner

```
-----------------------
 12    8     4    0
       9     5    1
       10    6    2 
       11    7    3 
-----------------------
```

By default it showing me like this

```
--------------------------
   0    4    8    12
   1    5    9
   2    6    10
   3    7    11
--------------------------
```

Because am dealing with some arabic app

Here 0,1,2,3,4 are `UICollectionViewCell`

i checked the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712201/ios-uicollectionview-default-flow-fill-rows-from-right-to-left) but its not working. Any idea how to deal with this.

Comment: any help for this above???

Comment: You can use transform - see answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598194/aligning-right-to-left-on-uicollectionview/27560079#27560079

Comment: Check this link, It may help you https://github.com/mokagio/UICollectionViewRightAlignedLayout