# Right aligned UICollectionView when using Horizontal scrolling with two items (for RTL)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, right-to-left

I am currently developing a project which supports Right-to-Left languages, too. So far, with RTL support of Apple, I managed %80 of the project to support RTL. However I am stuck with UICollectionView.

**For LTR Languages everything works fine as shown below:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**However**, when RTL is activated look below, the collection view is loading successfully but when it is trying to expand or in other words reload again, it acts like LTR again, i guess. I added slow motion gif in order to give you some information about the behaviour.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Any ideas why is this happening?
Please not, I referred to [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712201/ios-uicollectionview-default-flow-fill-rows-from-right-to-left/20803186#20803186), however it uses vertical scrolling, not horizontal.**

Answer (score 0):

-Are you sure your constraints in AutoLayout are right?
-Instead of setting RTL, 
 First when creating the UICollectionView perform a horizontal flip on it.
    `[collectionView_ setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];`

Then befor returning a cell in method CellForItemAtIndexPath give the cell a horizontal flip.

```
[cell setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];
```

Hope it will help.